# How to call nsobject class on a button in view controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller, nsobject

i am doing an apps which i need to call nsobject class in a view controller class, i try a couple method but its not working either i get a sigabrt error or the apps crash.

please help me.

I'm lost for days now.

any one have a sample code for calling nsobject from view controller?

thanks in advance for you kind help.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)firstButton;


@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TutoAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    UIButton *firstButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *firstButton;

@end
```

Comment: what do you mean by "call nsobject class"? some code please. the error normally means you call a method from a deallocated object, so try enable NSZombie and see

Comment: please, show some code. where does it crash?

Comment: as per code above i have a UiviewController and i want to call the nsobject using a button in UIViewController..

Comment: What do you mean by 'call the nsobject' ?

Comment: i want to call a window with a nsobject class from my viewController.. from a button that i put in the view controller XIB.. basically i have a code for gallery and i want to put a main window with a couple of button where when you click the button it will divert you to my gallery.. my main page is view controller and gallery is class from nsobject.. i just need the button to work ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please post some code where we can provide the correct solution. Even I don't get problem exactly but if you want to call class object then do the following.

```
-(void)buttoevent:(id)sender
{
  nsobjectclass *obj = [[nsobjectclass alloc]init];
  //if you want to call any method of that class then do the following.
  [obj methodname];
}
```

Comment: yup... i do want to call class object  can you explain more what should i put as nsobjectclass, obj and [obj method name] and where should i put this code in..

Comment: i try to use this but its not working.. how can i call the button on my view controller??

Comment: Ok. As per your above code what I understand you are trying to call appdelegate objects. So, first import TutoAppDelegate in your viewcontroller. then do the following:
TutoAppDelegate *tutoapp = [[uiapplication sharedapplication]delegate];

Comment: its the other way around sorry.. i am trying to call tutoAppDelegate from a button in viewcontroller

Comment: You can call appdelegate in your viewcontroller by above mentioned way.

Comment: viewController *view = [[UIApplication shareappication]delegate]; like this??

Comment: What exactly you want to do please be clear first. As you said you want to call nsobject class means appdelegate in your viewcontroller and hence for that my above is correct. try this first.

Comment: i want to call a window with a nsobject class from my viewController.. from a button that i put in the view controller XIB.. basically i have a code for gallery and i want to put a main window with a couple of button where when you click the button it will divert you to my gallery.. my main page is view controller and gallery is class from nsobject.. i just need the button to work ..

Comment: @Shy you currently seem to be very unsure on how to express your needs. That is because you have not understood the mechanics of programming, especially iOS programming at all. You should really keep on reading tutorials and references.

Comment: i just need this one thing and then i can complete my apps.. everything else already in place...

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if you have imported the class before using it